# How to set table as Postman.variables object

Tags: javascript, syntax, postman

I need to put table as new Postman variable, but I am probably doing something wrong with syntax, because when I try to used initialized table, there is "*Unexpected token in JSON*" error.

This is my initialization of table:

```js
pm.variables.set("cr", {crypt_arr: [
{
    key: "BTC",
    used: false
},
{
   key: "ETH",
    used: false 
},
{
   key: "XRP",
    used: false 
}]});
```

This is how I use this table. Maybe there is something wrong there:

```js
const crypto_arr = JSON.parse(pm.variables.get()).crypt_arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const crypto_arr = JSON.parse(pm.variables.get('cr')).crypt_arr;
```

you have to specify the variable name

Also you don't have to parse it as varible stored as object itself

```
   const crypto_arr = (pm.variables.get('cr')).crypt_arr;
```